# Selenium, load HTML with no media

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm using Selenium and Python2.7 to scrape some sites, the thing is that jumping from url to url is taking too much time because the selenium driver, using Firefox, waits until sound, pictures and videos finish loading. I want to know if there is anyway to just load the HTML and not wait for the media to load.

What my code looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
url_list = scrape_urls(driver.page_source)

for url in url_list:
    driver.get(url) # this line takes time to load
    scrape(driver.page_source)
```

Checking the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver), there is nothing that seems to do it.

Note: Manually clicking on the browser stop button does the trick.

Comment: Selenium probably isn't the tool for this job. Just use the requests library and get the markup directly.

Comment: yes you are right, I forgot to explain that I need to login to the site. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just configuring your Firefox not to load media?

Edit your Firefox about:config page and change these settings:

configplugins.click_to_play to true (for plugins like flash, silverlight etc)

permissions.default.image to 2 (doesn't automatically load images)